# NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO Exeception in Firefox 17 For Mac

Tags: angular, macos, firefox

In my website I used angular4 and when I checked the Firebox version 17 in Mac system console shows the error message:

> NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO: Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object in vendor.bundle.js

If any one has encountered this problem and solved it, how did you solve it?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `php` ?

Comment: Please clarify your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular [only](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2584) [supports](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support) the most recent versions of Firefox and Chrome, so I'd start by upgrading Firefox...